# ANTLR4 .net mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting

Tags: c#, .net, antlr4

Building a parser demo from a hello-world grammar, I cannot get it to work.

Grammar:

```
grammar Hello;
rule  :  'hello' ID ;     
ID : [a-z]+ ;             
WS : [ \t\n\r]+ -> skip ;
```

Code:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"c:\temp\input.txt");
var charStream = new AntlrInputStream(sr);
var lexer = new HelloLexer(charStream);
var tokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
var parser = new HelloParser(tokenStream);
parser.BuildParseTree = true;
var rcontext=parser.rule();
Console.WriteLine(rcontext.ToStringTree());
```

Libraries:
Antlr4.Runtime.Standard 4.13.0
antlr4buildtasks 12.2.0

Input:
hello myid
hello myid
hello myid

Output:
line 3:10 mismatched input '' expecting 'hello'
[]

Tried a few different things, but I am really stuck. I have tried to add EOF to the grammar and I have tried to add a "top-level" rule as well - to no effect.
This issue is described as a know issue in antlr4. The workarounds described does not seem to give another result.

Answer (score 0):

```
grammar Hello;
rule  :  'hello' ID ;     
ID : [a-z]+ ;             
WS : [ \t\n\r]+ -> skip ;
```

You need to tell ANTLR that it can occur more than once (and having an EOF on any start rule is always a good idea)

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense, however the issue persists, or maybe shows up in a different way. After parsing I do parser.rule() so that I can start my Visitor, but when I invoke rule() I get "...mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting 'Hello'..."

Comment: `grammar Hello;
production: rule1+ EOF;
rule  :  'Hello' ID ;     
ID : [a-z]+ ;             
WS : [ \t\n\r]+ -> skip ; `

Comment: ANTLR is case-sensitive by default. There’s an option you can use for case-insensitivity.  (Guessing that might have been the issue as your examples are not consistent with the h/H). You don’t have to break that into separate rules.

Comment: Oops, noticed I capitalized "Rule". I fixed it, and put the rest of your grammar in the answer (and tested at lab.antlr.org)

Comment: The upper case version was a trial - sorry, adding to the confusion. I tested it now at lab.antlr.org (brilliant tool btw!), and it also works for me in the lab, but not locally. As soon as I ask for ``HelloParser.ProductionContext productionContext = parser.production();`` I get the error. Using this grammar:``grammar Hello;
production: rule+ EOF;
rule  :  'hello' ID ;     
ID : [a-z]+ ;             
WS : [ \t\n\r]+ -> skip ; ``

Comment: My best guess at this point is that it's something with the creation of your input stream.  Unfortunately (for you), I'm on an M1 Mac and after a brief attempt to get C# and ANTLR set up, I'm hitting the wall on a couple of things, so I can't test under C#.

Comment: Thanks again - it is not obvious to me either. I now start over using vscode with the ANLTLR4 extension.

Comment: update - got it to work in vscode with a new template. Comparing references to libs etc. - all the same. Zoomed in on the only difference I could see: A debug statement I added in the lexer step to output the tokens:    ``var charStream = new AntlrInputStream(sr);
            var lexer = new HelloLexer(charStream);

            foreach (var item in lexer.GetAllTokens())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Channel + " " + item.Text + " " + item.Line + "/" + item.StartIndex + "/" + item.StopIndex);
            }``  No idea why, but removing these lines make it work!

Comment: It looks like GetAllTokens() just uses NextToken() which advances through the input stream, exhausting it.  You should look at the tokenStream to inspect your tokens (and be sure to Reset() your token stream back to the start before calling the parser)

Comment: Also, for future reference, test that the code you actually post, actually demonstrates the problem you’re asking about.  It’s easy to do some “clean up” of unimportant code and then forget to test that you still have your problem.

Comment: Completely agree - i just did not see the connection to the earlier part of the Process -